# How to Show/Display Product Cart Quantity in Product page using opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, product

I've searched and tried various approached using OC 2.3 .
I'm trying to display of individual product items already in cart on the Product page - any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: please upload with the proper questions. screenshot will be better for understand to developers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[![Current items Product in product page][2]][2]

Need to display how many items of individual product of current product page.
i entered code bellow but needs the value declared in controller i think.

```
<?php echo "CURRENT PRODUCT ITEMS IN CART: " . $products_quantity; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i entered the bellow declaration in catalog/controller/product/product.php,
it works but only when there is a product in the cart.

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {

            if ($product['quantity']) {
                $products_quantity = $product['quantity'];
                } 
            
            $data['products'] = array(
                'products_quantity'  => $product['quantity']
            );
                
                
$data['products_quantity'] = $products_quantity;

}
```